# Export to Excel using EPPlus worksheet name with space

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I have a working program that pull data from my database and export to Excel using EPPlus. However, the user specifically asked the name to be exactly how they want it, which contains white space in the worksheet name.
Currently I have the worksheet name as "Reorder_Point" and the program works just fine, but if I change it to "Reorder Point" it would error out. Anyone have any idea how to do this? Thanks!

```
string cnAPStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conAP_SQLWeb"].ConnectionString; ;
string queryReorder = "exec uspDataPull_ReorderPointInfo";
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cnAPStr);

SqlDataAdapter daReorder = new SqlDataAdapter(queryReorder, cn);
DataSet dsReorder = new DataSet();
daReorder.Fill(dsReorder);
dsReorder.Tables[0].TableName = "Reorder_Point";

DumpToExcel(dsReorder);

private void DumpToExcel(DataSet dsReorder)
{
    try
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            ExcelWorksheet ws1 = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dsReorder.Tables[0].TableName);
            ws1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dsReorder.Tables[0], true);
            using (ExcelRange rng = ws1.Cells["A1:AG1"])
            {
                rng.Style.Font.Bold = true;
            }

            string fileName = "RP_DataPull.xlsx";
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the Sheet a name instead of relying on the source column names.

```
ws1.Name = "Reorder Point";
```

Comment: For some strange reason what I had actually works, thanks for the reply anyway!